# Error creating bean with name (autowiring issue)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, classpath

I am new to Spring/Hibernate/Maven, I am getting the following [error](https://paste.ee/p/tnpst). I am using jdk 1.8 and Eclipse.

My project is divided into two Maven projects .

1. Frontend - consisting of jsp, controller etc
2. Backend - consisting of hibernete related stuff dao , services etc .

My controller class

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.xyz.retrospective.backend.dao.CommentDAO;



@Controller
public class PageController {

@Autowired
private CommentDAO commentDAO ;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
public ModelAndView index() {       
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");     
    return mv;  
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/${userId}/CurrentIteration")
public ModelAndView showCategoryProducts(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) 
{       
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("currentiteration");

    mv.addObject("commentTypeList",commentDAO.listCommentTypes());
    return mv;              
}   
 }
```

My dao class

```
package com.xyz.retrospective.backend.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.xyz.retrospective.backend.dto.CommentType;


public interface CommentDAO {

  List<CommentType> listCommentTypes();
}
```

My daoimpl class

```
package com.xyz.retrospective.backend.daoimpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.xyz.retrospective.backend.dao.CommentDAO;
import com.xyz.retrospective.backend.dto.CommentType;

 @Repository("commentDAO")
 public class CommentDAOImpl implements CommentDAO{

private static List<CommentType> commentTypes = new ArrayList<>();
static {
    CommentType ct1 = new CommentType();
    ct1.setCommentTypeId("1");
    ct1.setCommentTypeDescription("WhatWentWell");

    CommentType ct2 = new CommentType();
    ct2.setCommentTypeId("2");
    ct2.setCommentTypeDescription("WhatDidNot");

    CommentType ct3 = new CommentType();
    ct3.setCommentTypeId("3");
    ct3.setCommentTypeDescription("WhatCouldHaveBeenBetter");

    commentTypes.add(ct1);
    commentTypes.add(ct2);
    commentTypes.add(ct3);
}

@Override
public List<CommentType> listCommentTypes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return commentTypes;
}

}
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd       
">




<context:component-scan base-package="com.*"/>


    <!-- Loading static resources -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/resources/**" />



<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"/>





<bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
     <property name="viewResolvers" ref="viewResolver" />
</bean> 

</beans>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: It should working. Try to clean cache. If you running with Tomcat: right click on server and run: Clean Tomcat working directory and redeploy.

Comment: @AdamLesiak already tried that b4 posting here , its not working .

Comment: The paste containing the error has now been deleted, so this question no longer has an accurate problem statement that can keep it open. Would you be able to track down what the error was, so we can save it from closure? (This is why it is essential to put errors/logs/code/etc into posts themselves - not only does deletion represent a wasted opportunity to help other people, but if you get too many of these, it can restrict your future ability to post questions through an automated posting ban).

Comment: This question no longer contains an [mcve], so ought to be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Your maven build job for the front end is not packaging up back end classes and including them. You need to make another target that will compile required classes and make a jar that can be included in the front end build. or just make it 1 project.

Comment: Could u please elaborate "You need to make another target that will compile required classes and make a jar that can be included in the front end build." In my frontend iam having a dependency fro the backend . Is there anything else i need to do ?

Comment: when you say "having a dependency for the backend" do you mean import statements in your java. do you have items in your POM that that ensure your backend jar is included in the front end build. When you build the front end. open the jar with a zip program and see if the DAO is in there. For such a simple program i would suggest just having everything in 1 application instead of 2. If you are trying to practice multiple projects and dependencies then

Comment: Yes in pom of frontend iam having a dependency of backend , and in the backend pom iam packaging it as a jar .

Comment: Is there anything else missing that i have not done ?

Comment: if you open the client jar with a zip program do you see the DAO classes?

Comment: I see you have componenet scan on com.*  if you list the package for the backend jar specifically that may resolve it. the error you are getting in the stack trace basically says DAO is not on the classpath. so if it's in the jar the only thing else i can think of spring isn't picking it up in the client